# change location of image which is pulled in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml which is pulling an image. When i am running the docker-compose file. It throws no space error. How can i specify the path where the image is downloaded. it getting downloaded it root which just has 15gb. I want it to be downloaded in /home because it has a lot of space left.

Comment: You have to build it first from a Dockerfile, and then you can use it in your docker-compose file

Comment: You can't change it for individual images, but you can change Docker's global storage location.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the data root path of docker in the configuration file located by default `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. The property to change is `data-root`.

You can find out more in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file).